# Batch file that keeps the 7 latest files in a subfolder

Tags: file, batch-file, delete-file

Can anyone help me create a batch file? Basically, my goal is to create a batch file that will keep the latest 7 files (in other words, the newest) in the all folders from specify directory.

I got

```
set file2del=
for /f "skip=7" %%A in ('dir /b/o-d') do set file2del=%%A
if not "%file2del%"=="" del "%file2del%"
```

But this work for current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

First use `FOR /D` with the `/R` Switch to recursively loop on all folder (**from where the bat is started**). and apply the `FOR /F` loop on each directory.

```
@echo off

for /d /r %%a in (*) do (echo Treating Diretory ==^>  %%a
  for /f "skip=7" %%b in ('dir /b/o-d "%%a"') do del "%%a\%%b"
)
```

If you need something more detailled you can use a counter in place of the `SKIP=7` :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


for /d /r %%a in (*) do (echo Treating Diretory ==^>  %%a
  set /a $count=1
  for /f %%b in ('dir /b/o-d "%%a"') do (
          if !$count! LEQ 7 (
              echo Keeping File[!$count!] ==^> %%b
              set /a $count+=1
          ) else (echo Deleting File ==^> %%a\%%b
                  del "%%a\%%b")
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set "specificDir=c:\temp\"
for /f "skip=7" %%A in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d "%specificDir%"') do del "%%~fA"
```

should do. I added `/a-d` to exclude folders, used `%%~fA` to get the complete filename including drive/path and put quotes around it to safely process filenames (or paths) with spaces.