# How to copy top 15 txt files from one folder in c drive to another folder in c drive using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two folders in `C:` drive.

I want to copy top 15 txt files from one folder to another folder. *It is a daily repetitive task so I want to automate the process.*

How can I copy those txt using batch script?

This is what I have but it does not work.

```
xcopy /s "C:\Documents" "C:\research"
```

Comment: Please tell us what defines the **top 15 `.txt`** files.

Comment: I mean I want to copy first 15 files.

Comment: Please tell us what defines the **first 15 `.txt`** files.

Comment: I have 100 txt file in a folder. I want to copy only top 15 files which are recently generated.

Comment: **…** that's a little better, so can you confirm that you want the **15 most recently modified** or perhaps the **15 most recently created**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to batch-copy the 10 newest files to a directory in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440967/how-to-batch-copy-the-10-newest-files-to-a-directory-in-windows)

Comment: [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830101/batch-file-that-keeps-the-7-latest-files-in-a-subfolder/39834842#39834842)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "i=0"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\Documents" /O:-D') do if !i! lss 15 (
   copy "%%a" "C:\research"
   set /A i+=1
)
```

You may also add the `/T` switch in `dir` command to select the specific date used (creation, last access or last mod).

Comment: Thank you Aacini. In the code you have written above, if I have to copy only files that are created today then how do I do that?

Comment: My suggestion is that you accept an answer, _(if it provides the solution to your original question)_, then **start a new question**.

Answer (score -1):

I'd check this out:

[Batch file to copy files from one folder to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986447/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-folder)

I think this is what you're looking for but I'm not sure it'll guarantee the first 15 files.

Since you don't have spaces the "" aren't required.

```
xcopy /s C:\Documents\*.txt C:\research\*.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. It works to copy all the files not just recently created 15 files.

Comment: No problem, if you wouldn't mind marking this as an answer that'd help build up my reputation. :)

Comment: I tried to mark this as answer but it does not record my mark since I am new  to stackoverflow and I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: #ReputationProblems

Comment: Please only mark an answer if it specifically answers the question posed. As this code is written, and as indicated in the second comment below the answer, it copies all text files. The only way it would copy the 15 newest would be if there were exactly 15 there.